# Unbound value in class method

Tags: class, ocaml

I have this problem and i do not understand where it came from.
Code:

```
class applicationFrameworksManager =
object(this)
val mutable frameworks = []
method add_framework name = ()(* if not (List.mem name frameworks) then frameworks <- List.append frameworks [name]; *)
method get_frameworks = frameworks
```

end;;

And the error:

```
Error: Some type variables are unbound in this type:
     class applicationFrameworksManager :
       object
         val mutable frameworks : 'a list
         method add_framework : 'b -> unit
         method get_frameworks : 'a list
       end
   The method add_framework has type 'b -> unit where 'b is unbound
```

make: *** [genobjc.cmx] Error 2

Can anybody help? To what can i bound it? Thanks. I'll add to this class a lot of strings and i want to get at the end only the unique ones.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the type error (Jeffrey Scofield's answer is perfectly fine), but if your goal is to handle a lot of unique strings, you might prefer to use a set of string (http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Set.html) rather than a list. In addition, even with lists, `name::frameworks` is much more efficient than `List.append frameworks [name]` (in the latter, you'll go all over `frameworks` each time you add a fresh `name`, in the former you just add `name` in front of `frameworks`)

Comment: This also has nothing to see directly with your problem, but if you're a beginner with OCaml I recommend that you don't directly jump to the object-oriented programming style that you already know. OCaml is a sufficiently different language that different techniques are more convenient to use. If the use of object-oriented facilities is not imposed by your setting, you should try to avoid them and instead familiarize yourself with more "functional" ways of designing programs.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, can i iterate over the Set? I need to get them from there at some point. I've choose to manage everything inside the class and to not spread everything in my code because i have more methods and operations than i've posted here.

Comment: You can iterate over a set. The only point is that the `Set` module provides you a functor, that you have to instantiate with an appropriate module. In your case, you can do something like `module StringSet=Set.Make(String)`, then you can have `val mutable frameworks = StringSet.empty` `StringSet.add name frameworks` (without the need to check for membership), and `StringSet.iter f frameworks` where needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `[]` is polymorphic, hence its type `'a list` contains an unbound type variable.  The simple fix if you just want to add strings is to declare the type:

```
val mutable frameworks : string list = []
```

Your class as it stands is polymorphic; i.e., it could be used to manage lists of anything.  You can do this by explicitly giving the class a type parameter for the type of the managed elements.  But it sounds like you don't need that.

Comment: Thanks, i'm with ocaml for 2 weeks only and i have no idea why works, but works.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but the compiler is trying to tell you that it can't allow the methods `add_framework` and `get_frameworks` to have the types `'a -> unit` and `'a`.  The unbound type variables `'a` mean that you can pass anything at all and expect to get anything (else) at all back.  So you could store an `int` and expect to get a `string` back.  The point of the type system is to prevent this kind of thing.  So, you either have to specify a specific type, or make the type a parameter of the class.